# C++ static and non-static variable declaration in if condition

Tags: c++, g++, gnu

The following if conditions compile in Visual Studio C++:

```
if(int x = 5) { std::cout << x; }                  1
```

and

```
if(static int x = 5) { std::cout << x; }           2
```

On the other hand the gnu compiler only compiles the first one.
From testing it seems like the scope of the variable is just within the if condition.

However, since Visual studio compiles both version, I was wondering if there are any differences?

Answer (score 3):

According to C++ standard, the GNU is correct and VisualStudio is doing it wrong. Following 6.4/1:

```
condition:
    expression
    type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression
```

It is allowed to use *type-specifier-seq* and it can not contain *storage class specifier* such as `static`. To see what a type-specifier-seq can have, read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations).

Comment: You're referring to C++98 grammar, the code is valid.

Comment: The question is not specified the version, but my answer is an useful observation to find out where the problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid as of C++11:

```
condition: 
  expression 
  attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt decl-speciﬁer-seq declarator = initializer-clause 
  attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt decl-speciﬁer-seq declarator braced-init-list
```

A [defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1732) in the standard however allowed types to be defined in conditions, and this has been fixed for C++14, although due to the defect the GCC team seems to have held off on a [bugfix](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59729) that looks like it might fix this issue as well.